# Prevent Jenkins from building automatically on commit

Tags: git, jenkins, github

My ultimate goal is to allow our development team to deploy any branch that they are working on, on to our test environment.  However, I would like the deployment to be purely manual process.  Our development team commits frequently into the repository, and it would not be desireable to deploy on every commit.  I've got the Jenkins building and deploying our applications, but I can't figure out how I can trigger manually only.

I've got the Git section filled something like this:
[image: Jenkins Git Setup]

Also I have parameterized section like this:
[image: Git Parameters]

I can trigger the build manually, but it will also trigger when it detects a commit.  I would like to be able to disable build on commit.

So far, I've tried to click on the red X to remove "Branches to build".  It's removed, but when I navigate back to the Configuration page, it's back.  Looking the way it is on the picture.

Comment: Additional Behaviours > Don't trigger a build on commit notifications

Comment: @Tirex I expected it to be something simple that I missed, but it's easier than I had expected.  Thanks.